# How to access to test (devise) current_user in a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have used current_user in a helper as following:

```
module InvestorsHelper
  def single?
    binding.pry
    current_user.kyc.marital_status == 'Single'
  end

  def married?
    current_user.kyc.marital_status == 'Married'
  end

  def politically_exposed?
    current_user.kyc.is_politically_exposed.present?
  end

  def tax_residency?
    current_user.kyc.is_tax_residency.present?
  end
end
```

But how do I test those methods in rspec testing?

I wrote the following rspec code:

```
context "Investors Helper" do
    before(:each) do
      puts "Befpre exljfgd"
      current_user =    @user ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @kyc  ||= FactoryGirl.create(:kyc, user_id: @user.id)
    end

  describe InvestorsHelper, '#single?' do
    it 'returns status of current user' do

      result = InvestorsHelper.single?
      binding.pry
    end
end
```

end
end

But it returns the error:  NameError:

```
   undefined local variable or method `current_user' for InvestorsHelper:Module
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `InvestorsHelper` doesn't define `current_user`, so you are getting that error message. It looks like `InvestorsHelper` is meant to be a mix-in, so I would either test something it's mixed into instead or mix it into a mock class that defines `current_user` and test that.

In addition, I'm surprised your code fails there and not on `InvestorsHelper.single?`. Calling the method like that will try to call the singleton method `::single?` (usually defined with `def self.single?`) but you've declared it as an instance method in your code.